# How to use calcuted date in a mongodb filter?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to filter for documents that are within the last minute. But the following query, with a calculated `$gte` time, does not work.

```
db.mycollection.aggregate([
    {$match: {
       "properties.time": {$gte: {$subtract: [ISODate(), 60000]}}
    }}
])
```

It doesn't return anything, but not because there are no dates within the last minute. As far I can tell from projecting the calculated date in queries that do work, the calculated date is correct. Is there some reason that you cannot use a calculated value in this way?

The following query, with a hard-coded time, does work:

```
db.mycollection.aggregate([
    {$match: {
       "properties.time": {$gte: ISODate("2018-12-26T12:00:00Z")}
    }}
])
```

I also considered calculating the age in seconds and then filtering based on that. The following also does work.

```
db.mycollection.aggregate([
    {$project: {
        "properties.time": "$properties.time",
        "age": {$subtract: [ISODate(), "$properties.time"]}
    }},
    {$match: {
        "age": {$lte: 60000}
    }}
])
```

But that's not a good solution because

- really, I want to include the filter in a `$geoNear` query, and since `$geoNear` has to be the first step in the pipeline, I can't project the age and then use it in the `$geoNear`
- I want to use the index on `"properties.time"`

We're using eve, so another workaround would be to convert the requested `max_age` parameter to a `start_time` in a hook. But it really seems like that first approach should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an aggregation [expression](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#aggregation-expressions) inside `$match` so you have to use [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) operator, try:

```
db.mycollection.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            $expr: {
                $gte: [ "$properties.time", { $subtract: [ISODate(), 60000] } ]
            }
        }
    }
])
```

You can use [$redact](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) as a fallback for MongoDB lower than 3.6, try:

```
db.mycollection.aggregate([
    {
        $redact: {
            $cond: {
                if: { $gte: [ "$properties.time", { $subtract: [ISODate(), 60000] } ] },
                then: "$$KEEP",
                else: "$$PRUNE"
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Hmmm, our mongo version is too old. Any chance there is another way to do this? Also, I assume that this doesn't use the index on properties.time, either? It's looking like the better solution will be to use a `start_time` rather than a `max_age` and handle the calculation before the aggregation.

Comment: @jmilloy you can try $redact as a fallback

Comment: Okay, that's useful. In this case, I don't think it's any better than the project version I included above because I can't use it in a geoNear.